# Boku no Hero Academia season 3 episode 10 OST?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the song that plays at season 3 episode 10 at 20 minutes of *Boku no Hero Academia*? It's also in episode 4 at minute 18, and I can't find it.

Answer (score -1):

Hello i think that's the music that you were searching for :)

https://youtu.be/BsbVtAJMHys

Comment: Hey! Welcome to A&M. Could you maybe add a bit more detail to your answer? Like who the singer/artist is, and what the song is actually called? All though this link might answer the question, the video might be removed as well. Leaving everybody with an incomplete answer. You can [Add this information](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/48326/edit) through the [Edit](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/48326/edit) button underneath your post

Comment: In addition to the above suggestion, is it the official title? Has the album officially been released? This video states "One For All vs All For One", but I saw another which says "All Might vs All For One"...